# Wildfly Undertow directory listing - sorting file

Tags: sorting, wildfly, undertow, directory-listing

I use undertow to serve some app logs, but I can't figure out how to sort files, for example for modification time... is there a way?

This is the subsystem conf:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
     ...
     <server name="default-server">
         ...
         <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
             ...
             <location name="/logs" handler="logs"/>
             ...
         </host>
         ...
     </server>
     ...
     <handlers>
         ...
         <file name="logs" path="/home/app/logs" directory-listing="true"/>
     </handlers>
     ...
</subsystem>
```

Comment: You'd have to write this yourself.  The default implementation can't account for all  possible use cases.

Comment: @stdunbar surely, you're right. But I thought that sorting files was a basic option for directory listing. How can I implement that?

Comment: A basic servlet would do, depending on your needs.  [Here is an example](https://github.com/kristian/file-manager-servlet/blob/master/src/main/java/lc/kra/servlet/FileManagerServlet.java) that could get you started.